# POI XSSFWorkbook cloning/copy/duplicating

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I want to open an excel file in POI using OPCPackage and XSSFWorkbook.  Since this file will be used in different threads, I want to avoid reopening the file to save time (POI is slow in opening an xlsx file).  So what I did was to save the workbook in a global variable then the thread will just access this global variable and reuse the object.

The problem that I encountered was when I tried to reuse the object, it affects/modifies the original data of the excel file.

I tried to make a copy of the workbook from the global variable by cloning or serialization but I am encountering an error on both processes.

Is there a way to create a new copy from an existing XSSFWorkbook object and using this new copy will not affect the data of the original file?

Here is my code in opening an excel file:

```
OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(new File("c:/sample.xlsx"));
XSSFWorkbook wb = (XSSFWorkbook) WorkbookFactory.create(pkg);
```

I want to create a new copy of the "wb" object and save it in another variable.

Comment: Do you mean it modifies the original file when you use `wb.write()` or do you want to have two versions of the workbook in you application? The original and a modified one.

Comment: What happens if you open the original file read only, rather than read-write?

Comment: @Sebastian_H Yes it also modifies the original file and Yes I want to have two versions of the workbook that I opened.

Comment: @Gagravarr I cannot open the workbook as read only as I needed to create an archive of the workbook and save it on a different location at the end of the process.

Comment: @Tina do you have any solution? I am also interested

Comment: @Tina have you found any solution ?

Comment: @GelinLuo have you found any solution ?

Comment: @PrakashBist no I haven't

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar exercise and my solution was to use the Create method of the WorkbookFactory class, passing it an InputStream object from the source file. Is the next:

```
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream (origin_file)
XSSFWorkbook wb = (XSSFWorkbook) WorkbookFactory.create (inputStream)
XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheet (sheet)
...
FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream ("new_file.xlsx")
wb.write (file)
file.close ()
```